# Store Content in Confluence Cloud from Python Script running in cron

Tags: confluence

Is there a way of adding external content to Confluence Cloud from a python script?

I have a load of data that I want to show in confluence. This data can only be retrieved via an API however i don't want to include the API credentials in a js plugin as that would be a security issue. I would therefore like to have a script running on a cron that will get the data and store it in confluence. Confluence can then just lookup the data locally and i don't need to include any api credentials in any plugins.

I know that data can be stored from within Confluence using a form as shown in the tutorial https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/lesson-2-adding-content-customers-ahoy/ but i'm not sure if this can be imported for an external script?

I found this page that gives info for if Confluence is hosted locally https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/ does anyone know if there is something like this for the cloud version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found how to do this now. There are docs here if anyone else needs to know https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/

Comment: I'm no Stackoverflow expert Sam but I believe you should accept your answer so that this is no longer unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @ScottWelker I would love to but unfortunately stack overflow won't allow me to accept my own answer for two days!! This doesn't make sense to me but i'm sure they have their reasons.

Comment: See. Told you I was no SO expert :-/